# Как разбить автоматически список выводов БД на страницы (redbeanphp)?

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Подскажите, к примеру в БД есть 100 записей. Они все выводятся, подряд, но как сделать так, чтобы автоматически разбить их на страницы, допустим 10 записей на 1 стр.? И при дальнейшем добавлении постов страницы добавлялись сами (наподобие wordpress). Пример нужен на **RedBeanPHP**

*Пример вывода всех записей подряд:*

```
<?php
$posts = R::findAll('posts');
foreach ($posts as $post) {
echo $post->head, '<br>';
echo $post->desc,'<br><br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Опишу свой способ, как я делаю, работает на реальных проектах.

Для начала я написал свой собственный класс для пагинации, код ниже

```
<?php

namespace Web\App;

use RedBeanPHP\R;

class Paginate
{
    public $items;
    public $limit;
    public $page;
    public $order_by = '';
    public $group_by = '';
    public $active;
    public $start;
    public $count_pages;
    public $absolute_path = true;
    public $query_string = '';

    private $count = 0;
    private $url_first_page;
    private $url_page;
    private $table = '';
    private $sql_filter;

    public function __construct($table, $sql_filter = '', $items = 20)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
        $this->items = $items;
        $this->sql_filter = $sql_filter;

        return $this;
    }

    private function set()
    {
        $this->set_page();

        $this->active = $this->page;
        $this->start = ($this->page - 1) * $this->items;

        $this->set_limit();
        $this->set_url_page();
        $this->set_query_string();

        $this->set_count();
        $this->count_pages = ceil($this->count / $this->items);
        $this->save_to_session();

        return $this;
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $this->set();
        return $this;
    }

    // PUBLIC SETTERS
    public function setOrderBy($p1, $p2 = 'DESC')
    {
        $this->order_by = "\n ORDER BY $p1 $p2";
        return $this;
    }

    public function setGroupBy($p)
    {
        $this->group_by = "\n GROUP BY $p";
        return $this;
    }

    public function setItems($p)
    {
        $this->items = $p;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setSQLFilter($p)
    {
        $this->sql_filter = $p;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setAbsolutePath(bool $p)
    {
        $this->absolute_path = $p;
        return $this;
    }

    // PRIVATE SETTERS
    private function set_page()
    {
        $this->page = isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']) ? abs(intval($_GET['page'])) : 1;
    }

    private function set_limit()
    {
        $this->limit = "\n LIMIT $this->start, $this->items \n";
    }

    private function set_count()
    {
        $this->count = R::count($this->table, $this->sql_filter);
    }

    private function set_query_string()
    {
        if ($this->sql_filter != '') $this->sql_filter = 'WHERE ' . $this->sql_filter;

        $this->query_string = $this->sql_filter . $this->group_by . $this->order_by . $this->limit;
    }

    private function set_url_page()
    {   
        $p = '?';
        foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) if ($k != 'page') $p .= "$k=$v&";

        $url = mb_strlen($p) > 1 ? mb_substr($p, 0, -1) : '?';

        list($path) = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        if ($this->absolute_path)
            $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $path;

        $this->url_first_page = $path . $url;
        $this->url_page = $p == '?' ? $path . '?page=' : $path . $url . '&page=';
    }

    private function save_to_session()
    {
        if (!$this->isSessionStart()) session_start();

        $_SESSION['new_paginate'] = [
            'all' => $this->count,
            'url_first_page' => $this->url_first_page,
            'url_page' => $this->url_page,
            'items' => $this->items,
            'active' => $this->active,
            'start' => $this->start,
            'count_pages' => $this->count_pages
        ];
    }

    // DISPLAY BUTTONS
    public static function display()
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['new_paginate'])) return;

        $url = $_SESSION['new_paginate']['url_first_page'];
        $url_page = $_SESSION['new_paginate']['url_page'];
        $active = $_SESSION['new_paginate']['active'];
        $count_pages = $_SESSION['new_paginate']['count_pages'];
        $prev = $active == 2 ? $url : $url_page . ($active - 1);
        $next = $url_page . ($active + 1);

        $start = 1;
        if ($_SESSION['new_paginate']['count_pages'] > 1) {
            $left = $active - 1;
            $right = 5 - $active;
            $start = $active - 1 < floor(5 / 2) ? 1 : $active - floor(5 / 2);
            $end = $start + 4;
            if ($end > $count_pages) {
                $start -= $end - $count_pages;
                $end = $count_pages;
                $start = $start < 1 ? 1 : $start;
            }
        }

        if ($count_pages > 1) { ?>
            <ul class="pagination">
                <?php if ($active != 1) { ?>
                    <li><a class="arrow" href="<?= $prev ?>" title="Previous page">&laquo;</a></li>
                    <?php if (!in_array($active, [2, 3])) { ?>
                        <li><a href="<?= $url ?>">1</a></li>
                        <?php if ($active != 4) { ?>
                            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) { ?>
                    <?php if ($i == $active) { ?>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#"><?= $i ?><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <li><a href="<?= $i == 1 ? $url : $url_page . $i ?>"><?= $i ?></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($active != $count_pages) {
                    if (!in_array($count_pages, [2, 3, 4, 5]) and !in_array($active, [$count_pages - 1, $count_pages - 2])) {
                        if (!in_array($count_pages - $active, [1, 2]) and !in_array($count_pages, [5, 6]) and ($count_pages - 3) != $active) { ?>
                            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <li><a href="<?= $url_page . $count_pages ?>"><?= $count_pages ?></a></li>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    <li><a class="arrow" href="<?= $next ?>" title="Next page">&raquo;</a></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        <?php }

    }

    // PRIVATE HELPERS
    private function isSessionStart()
    {
        if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '<')) return session_id() == '' ? false : true;
        else return session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ? false : true;
    }
}
```

Использую таким образом

```
    $str = '`purchases`.`status` = 0 AND `purchases`.`type` = 1';

    // пагинация
    $p = (new Paginate('purchases'))
        ->setSQLFilter($str)
        ->setGroupBy('purchases.id')
        ->setOrderBy('purchases.id')
        ->get();

    // запрос
    return R::getAll("SELECT `purchases`.*,
            `manufacturers`.`name` AS `manufacturer_name`,
            `storage`.`name` AS `storage_name`,
            SUM(`pp`.`amount` * `pp`.`price`) AS `full_sum`,
            IF(`purchases`.`type` = 1 AND `purchases`.`status` = 2 , 1, 0) AS `close` 
        FROM `purchases`
        LEFT JOIN `storage` ON (`storage`.`id` = `purchases`.`storage_id`)
        LEFT JOIN `manufacturers` ON (`manufacturers`.`id` = `purchases`.`manufacturer`)
        LEFT JOIN `purchases_products` AS `pp` ON (`pp`.`purchases_id` = `purchases`.`id`)
        {$p->query_string}");

    // ну или такой запрос
    R::findAll('posts', $p->query_string);
```

на страницу вывожу таким образом

```
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <?php \Web\App\Paginate::display() ?>
    </div>
```

При подключении Bootstrap 3 кнопки автоматически стилизируются, но можете прописать свои стили.

Comment: как это все печально выглядит

Comment: @teran возможно, но это я делал под себя суто, +класс до конца не дописан. для моих нужд полностью хватает. Как пример думаю норм.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытались почитать [документацию](https://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/finding_beans)?

```
$page = intval($_GET['page']);
$itemsPerPage = 10;
$offset = ($page - 1)*$itemsPerPage;

$posts = R::findAll('posts', "ORDER BY head LIMIT $offset, $itemsPerPage");
```

или

```
$posts = R::find('posts',  "ORDER BY head LIMIT ?, ? ", [$offset, $limit]);
```

Comment: да, только она не работает

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий вариант, давно использовал, должно работать, стили bootstrap уже заданы для пагинации.

```
//Пагинация. Считаем сколько строк в БД
            $total = R::count( 'posts' );

            // Сколько выводить на страницу
            $limit = 30;

            // Сколько будет страниц
            $pages = ceil($total / $limit);

            // На какой странице мы находимся сейчас?
            $page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
            'options' => array(
            'default'   => 1,
            'min_range' => 1,
            ),
            )));

            // Вывод страниц и других значений на страницу
            $offset = ($page - 1)  * $limit;
            $start = $offset + 1;
            $end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);


            //Для вывода нумерации
            $number = 3; //кол-во до и после ссылок

            $start_number = ($page > $number) ? $page - $number : 1; 
            $end_number = ($page < ($pages - $number)) ? $page + $number : $pages;

                $posts = R::findAll( 'posts', 'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT '.$limit.' OFFSET '.$offset.'' );

echo '<ul class="pagination pagination-lg">';

                    $prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<li><a href="?page=1" title="Первая страница">&laquo;</a></li> <li><a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Предыдущая страница">Предыдущая</a></li>' : '<li class="disabled"><a class="disabled">&laquo;</a></li> <li class="disabled"><a class="disabled">Предыдущая</a></li>';
                    $nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<li><a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '" title="Следующая страница">Следующая</a></li> <li><a href="?page=' . $pages . '" title="Последняя страница">&raquo;</a></li>' : ' <li class="disabled"><a class="disabled">Следующая</a></li> <li class="disabled"><a class="disabled">&raquo;</a></li>';

                    echo $prevlink;
                    for ($i = $start_number; $i <= $end_number; $i++) {
                        $link_active = ($page == $i) ? 'class="page-item active"' : 'class="page-item"';
                        $numbers = '<li '.$link_active.'><a class="page-link" href="index.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                        echo $numbers;              
                    }   
                    echo $nextlink;


                    echo '</ul></div>';
```